# Find multiple maxima of vector for a moving window

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 1D matrix `x` and I want for specific iterations to slide the analyse window, so that every time it moves by 20 samples with 50% overlap. I found `bsxfun` but i don't know how to adjust it to my problem.

I wrote the below code but I'm not getting the results I expect. I need to get for every iteration the max value of `autocorr`, for every overlapping window. I get an error for the number of lags.

```
x = rand(1,100);
N = length(x); % length of signal
n1 = 20;  % length of analysing window

win_num = floor((N/n1)*2-1); % number of windows
for i=1:win_num
   xmax(i) = max(bsxfun(@autocorr,x(1:n1/2:N),win_num-1));
end
```

Comment: Please describe the issue with the code you posted. Is it to slow? Is it not working?

Comment: yes the code is not working, i need to get the max values for each iteration , and without the bsxfun i got always the max for the whole x

Comment: If you have the Image processing toolbox, you can use the sliding max filter called [`imdilate`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html). Will work for 1D as well as 2D data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your loop as follows, to make it work:

```
x = rand(1,100);   %// example data
N = length(x)      %// length of signal
n = 20             %// length of analysing window

for ii = n/2:n/2:N-1
    xmax(ii*2/n) = max( x( ii-n/2+1 : ii+n/2) );
end
```

---

A [**vectorized**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) version could be:

```
xmax = max( x( bsxfun(@plus, (1:n).',0:n/2:N-n) ) )
```

**Explanation:**

```
%// create index matrix with moving window
idx = bsxfun(@plus, (1:n).',0:n/2:N-n);   %'
%// get values of original vector
xM =  x( idx );
%// find maximimum in dimension 1
xmax = max( xM ).'
```